# table view dissappears when changing from portrait to landscape view xcode

Tags: uitableview, xcode4, uiinterfaceorientation

i am working on a project which has a mapview on top and table view  on the bottom , and i tried to make the app adjustable to the different view orientations by using the following code,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:      
(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{


    return YES;
}
```

but when i change the view from portrait to landscape view the table view gets dissappeared ,
how can i make this work , any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanking you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the table view was hiding down below in landscape view , i had to hardcode the position and height of the table view to get it to display on the same height and position on both portrait and landscape view

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:     (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
 if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) {
     CGRect tableViewFrame = [tableView frame];
     tableViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
     tableViewFrame.origin.y = 500;         
     tableViewFrame.size.height=500;
     [tableView setFrame:tableViewFrame];
 }
 else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)){
     CGRect tableViewFrame = [tableView frame];
     tableViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
     tableViewFrame.origin.y = 755;         
     tableViewFrame.size.height=500;
     [tableView setFrame:tableViewFrame];
 }

return YES;
}
```